# Emitting IronPython code in C#

Tags: c#, ironpython, reflection.emit

Basically I have two questions:

1) How to emit or generate a `IronPython` code (tools, libs) in a C# application. The result of this process should be string consisting of real `IronPython` code not IL code.

2) How beneficial is the approach above over generating a `IronPython` code on your own (simply by using `StringBuilder`)?

I am looking for some code generator library similar to this IMAGINARY pseudo code generator:

```
IronPythonCodeGenerator generator = new IronPythonCodeGenerator();
Parameter param = new Parameter("str");
ParameterValue value=new ParameterValue(param,"This piece is printed by the generated code!!!");
Function function = IronPythonCodeGenerator.CreateFunction("PrintExtended",param);
function.AppendStatement("print",param);
function.AppendStatement(Statements.Return);
FunctionCall functionCall = new FunctionCall(function,value);
generator.MainBody.Append(function);
generator.MainBody.Append(functionCall);

Console.WriteLine(generator.MainBody.ToString());
```

, which outputs the IronPython code:

```
def PrintExtended( str ):
   print str;
   return;

PrintExtended("This piece is printed by the generated code!!!");
```

Comment: There is a [Reflector plugin](http://ipreflector.codeplex.com/) for generating IronPython code from IL. Reflector, in case you don't know, is a program that decompiles .NET assemblies.

Comment: Can I get feedback what is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reflection.Emit` is for generating IL code, not for generating high-level language code. So if your target language is IronPython, building it up in a `StringBuilder` is probably your best bet.

It of course depends on your needs. If all you want to do is just generate code without wanting to change the order of methods, or modify methods after they've been defined etc., just constructing code in a `StringBuilder` and then compiling it would be the easiest way.

Comment: What if I wanted the IL code to be converted to IronPython code. Is there any existing library which can help me to do it?

Comment: You mean a decompiler? So you would emit IL, and then decompile it to IronPython? Why would you want to do that? I know that Telerik's JustDecompile comes with an API but I'm not sure if it can generate any specific language. See http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx if you want to find out.

Comment: I am interested in building IronPython code at high level not needing to worry about low level construction (string concatenations) and statements constructions. Building the code by using Reflection.Emit is something in the middle which is not perfect but also not the worst one. The most reliable and suitable way for me would be the one I presented in the edited question. So I am looking for easiest, strongly typed generation and time efficient solution.